# Remove children with defined attribute - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to remove children DIV elements of a parent with certain attribute. I have it half working, but with the below code, it doesn't find the children

**HTML**

```
<div id="PremiumGiftContainer" class="PremiumGiftContainer">

     <div class='message' is-vip='false'>
      <p>FALSE</p>
    </div> 

    <div class='message'  is-vip='false'>
      <p>FALSE</p>
    </div>

    <div class='message'  is-vip='true'>
      <p>TRUE</p>
    </div>

</div>

<button id="button">Remove</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  remove_element();
})

function remove_element(){

      $('#PremiumGiftContainer').children(function () {

        $("[is-vip]").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr('is-vip')=='true'){
            $(this).fadeOut();
          }
        });

      })
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/SteveV/yoj4n2mk/)**

If I remove the **$('#PremiumGiftContainer').children...** section, it works, but I was trying to limit the scope of the search that needs to happen to find the correct switches.

Is what I'm trying to do achievable?

Answer (score 3):

`children()` does not accept a function, it takes a selector. As such you can simply use an attribute selector and then call `fadeOut()` on the resulting elements.

Also note that you should not create your own non-standard attributes on elements. If you want to store custom data with an element, use a `data-*` attribute.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  remove_element();
})

function remove_element() {
  $('#PremiumGiftContainer').children('[data-is-vip="true"]').fadeOut();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PremiumGiftContainer" class="PremiumGiftContainer">
  <div class="message" data-is-vip="false">
    <p>FALSE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message" data-is-vip="false">
    <p>FALSE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message" data-is-vip="true">
    <p>TRUE</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="button">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Ah!! Thanks Rory, that makes total sense and completely didn't think to research if `children()` accepted functions. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Can do this with one selector using an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

```
$('#PremiumGiftContainer > [is-vip=true]').fadeOut()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yoj4n2mk/8/)**</kbd>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan right...added children in selector, not sure if that even matters though

Comment: Why would you add a direct child selector `>`? And why would you create a demo on JSFiddle instead of what's preferred, here?

Comment: @connexo only because Op started with `children`. Doubt it really matters. With markup shown would work with or without it

Comment: @connexo that's not true. think you are confusing `find()` and `children()`